# Typescript 2604 errors start occurring throughout my NextJS react project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm failing to build my Next app because of multiple typescript errors in code that was previously type-checked, build and working fine. The type errors are always 2604 errors, e.g:

```
JSX element type 'Link' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)
```

The errors occur while using custom components wrapped with a forwardRef, as well as standard NextJS components such as `Link`.

I have not updated my next version (12.2.5), nor the tsconfig.json file.

I build a dummy component, implementing a Link component as described in the Next.js documentation:

```
import Link from 'next/link'

interface TestProps {}

export default function Test({}: TestProps){
  return (
    <>
    <h1>Test component</h1>
    <Link href="/"></Link>
    </>
  )
}
```

It still gave me a 2604 error on the `<Link>` component.

What changed here? I am trying to solve the source of the error, not merely ignore it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, make sure to have the appropriate version of @types/react imported in your project (in sync with your react version).

Comment: The react version is "18.2.0", the @types/react version is "18.0.18". This should not be the issue as no changes have occurred in the installed (type) dependencies since the last functioning, type-checked build.